# Why neo4j is not adding a new line with \n character coming in data from csv?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am having some data coming from csv which has \n character in it and I expect neo4j to add a new line when assigning that string to some attribute in node. Apparently its not working. I can see \n character as it is added in the string.

How to make it work? Thanks in Advance.

Following is one such string example from CSV:

```
Combo 4 4 4 5 \n\nSpare Fiber Inventory. \nMultimode Individual fibers from 9927/9928 to FDB.\nNo available spares from either BTS to FDB - New conduits would be required\n\nFrom FDB to tower top. 9 of 9 Spares available on 2.5 riser cables.
```

My load command:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///abc.csv' AS line
WITH line WHERE line.parent <> "" AND line.type = 'LSD' AND line.parent_type = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: The character `\n` will be stored as `\n`, it's just when you fetch and print it, then it acts as a newline character.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor The GUI system which shows this data is actually showing all of \n as it is in a text box so it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add some sample csv data here?

Comment: Combo 4 4 4 5  \n\nSpare Fiber Inventory. \nMultimode Individual fibers from 9927/9928 to FDB.\nNo available spares from either BTS to FDB - New conduits would be required\n\nFrom FDB to tower top. 9 of 9 Spares available on 2.5 riser cables.

Comment: Please add it in the question, along with the import command that you are using

Comment: I tried it, it stores as `\n` in a node attribute, but it renders newline, if I log that attribute in any programming languae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack that I made to replace the occurrences of \n with a newline. The character \ is an escape character so it will replace \n with a new line in line 4.  Do not remove line 5 and combine with line 4.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM 'file:///abc.csv' AS line
WITH line WHERE line.parent <> ""
WITH replace(line.parent,'\\n',"   
") as parent
MERGE (p:Parent {parent: parent})
```

RESULT:

```
{
  "identity": 16,
  "labels": [
    "Parent"
  ],
  "properties": {
"parent": "Combo 4 4 4 5    
   
Spare Fiber Inventory.    
Multimode Individual fibers from 9927/9928 to FDB.   
No available spares from either BTS to FDB - New conduits would be required   
   
From FDB to tower top. 9 of 9 Spares available on 2.5 riser cables."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the same replace.

Comment: Great! pls click the Accept button on my answer.